# Trying to install hadoop on raspberry pi3, not able to start name node

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, raspberry-pi3, namenode

Hi all I am trying to install hadoop on raspberry pi3, I am able to run all but name node,I searched all sources possible but I couldnt find any such problem elsewhere, the java version that my PI is running on is jdk.1.7

here are my configuration parameters:

Hadoop-env.sh

```
# The maximum amount of heap to use, in MB. Default is 1000.
#export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=
#export HADOOP_NAMENODE_INIT_HEAPSIZE=""

# Extra Java runtime options.  Empty by default.
# export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
# export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -XX:-PrintWarnings -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.library.path=$HADOOP_HOME/lib/native"

# Command specific options appended to HADOOP_OPTS when specified
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
export HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=ERROR,RFAS $HADOOP_DATANODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS="-Dhadoop.security.logger=${HADOOP_SECURITY_LOGGER:-INFO,RFAS} -Dhdfs.audit.logger=${HDFS_AUDIT_LOGGER:-INFO,NullAppender} $HADOOP_SECONDARYNAMENODE_OPTS"

export HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS="$HADOOP_NFS3_OPTS"
export HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_PORTMAP_OPTS"

# The following applies to multiple commands (fs, dfs, fsck, distcp etc)
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx512m $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
#HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS="-XX:-UsePerfData $HADOOP_JAVA_PLATFORM_OPTS"

# On secure datanodes, user to run the datanode as after dropping privileges.
# This **MUST** be uncommented to enable secure HDFS if using privileged ports
# to provide authentication of data transfer protocol.  This **MUST NOT** be
# defined if SASL is configured for authentication of data transfer protocol
# using non-privileged ports.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER=${HADOOP_SECURE_DN_USER}

# Where log files are stored.  $HADOOP_HOME/logs by default.
#export HADOOP_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/$USER

# Where log files are stored in the secure data environment.
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_LOG_DIR=${HADOOP_LOG_DIR}/${HADOOP_HDFS_USER}

###
# HDFS Mover specific parameters
###
    # Specify the JVM options to be used when starting the HDFS Mover.
# These options will be appended to the options specified as HADOOP_OPTS
# and therefore may override any similar flags set in HADOOP_OPTS
#
# export HADOOP_MOVER_OPTS=""

###
# Advanced Users Only!
###

# The directory where pid files are stored. /tmp by default.
# NOTE: this should be set to a directory that can only be written to by 
#       the user that will run the hadoop daemons.  Otherwise there is the
#       potential for a symlink attack.
export HADOOP_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}
export HADOOP_SECURE_DN_PID_DIR=${HADOOP_PID_DIR}

# A string representing this instance of hadoop. $USER by default.
export HADOOP_IDENT_STRING=$USER
export JAVA_HOME=$(readlink -f /usr/bin/java | sed "s:bin/java::")
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=250
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>fs.default.name</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
      <property>
        <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>
      </property>
      <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>file:/opt/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/namenode</value>
      </property>
      <property>
            <name>dfs.datanode.name.dir</name>
            <value>file:/opt/hadoop/hadoop_data/hdfs/datanode</value>
      </property>
    </configuration>
```

after running ./start-dfs.sh and ./start.yarn.sh, when I type jps the following nodes deamons are visible

```
   13018 SecondaryNameNode
   12735 DataNode
   13265 ResourceManager
   13382 NodeManager
   17525 Jps
```

would like to know what i am doing wrong